# dlopen and shared objects 'pointers'

Tags: unix, dlopen

Is it possible to successfully call `dlopen()` on a shared object that 'points' to another shared object? For example, I'd like to dynamically open the library `/usr/lib/libpanel.so`. However, it is not an actual library; rather, it 'points' to `/usr/lib/libpanelw.so`:

```
$ cat /usr/lib/libpanel.so
INPUT(-lpanelw)
```

With `dlopen()` I get a `file too short` error. Is there any way to successfully load these kinds of libraries?

(Bonus Question: what is the actual term for these kinds of libraries?)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this through symbolic links. Chances are high that your system already does exactly that with many standard .so's.

Try `ln -s /usr/lib/libpanelw.so /usr/lib/libpanel.so`